# POI XSSF and SXSSF

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am writing an application to use JAVA POI to read over 65536 records from oracle table and write to EXCEL .XLSX via JAVA POI library `XSSF` and `SXSSF`.

However, the error "out of memory" pops up. We have tried the following ways but the problem still occurs.

- Load 66000 records into memory and write to .XLSX file
  a.  Larger heap size “`Java.exe  –Xmx4096m –Xmx4096m –XX:MaxPermSize=256m`” is applied

Result : It takes about an hour to run and the file cannot be created.

- Process  66000 records by region
  a.  load each region records’ of a season from oracle table into memory
  b.  append each region records from memory to a single .XLSX file
  c.  Larger heap size `Java.exe  –Xmx4096m –Xmx4096m –XX:MaxPermSize=256m` is applied

Result : When it processes about 30000 records,  the java memory error still pops up.

Except rewriting the program by using XML, is there any chance of fixing the memory error issue of JAVA POI `XSSF` and `SXSSF` ?

Please kindly advise

Comment: Do you know if the input file is giving you the problem? In other words, if you comment out everything you are doing to the file, and simply read it in, do you run out of memory?

Comment: Are you sure that the Apache POI part is the problem? Writing 65k records with POI takes some memory, but not 4gb worth. I'd suggest you check the rest of your code (including DB parts) to see where your memory is going

Comment: yes. when we use HSSF to write the records around 65K, it works. However, when we use SXSSF and XSSF to write record around 65K, there is memory error